# WP Job Manager - Claim Listing - template override - folder name

Tags: wordpress

I need to override a WC Job Manager - Claim Listing add-on template file, but I can't figure out what should be the name of the folder in my child theme.

There's a help page on overriding the WPJM add-on templates here, but 'Claim Listing' addon is just not there.

https://wpjobmanager.com/document/overriding-add-template-files/

I've tried all the obvious folder names like

wp-job-manager-claim-listing
claim-listing
claim_listing
wp-claim-listing

but nothing works. Would anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `wpjmcl` !

Nothing in the help docs, it should be more obvious ..